# Good practice for combining features of views in a customview

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing a custom `View` which extends from `RelativeLayout`, 
containing two `ImageView`s and one `EditText` as child views.

I want one `ImageView` and the `EditText` act like one `View`. So if the user clicks on one of these, they should both gain the focus which should be visualized to the user as follows. The default focus animation for the EditText should remain and the the image drawable on the `ImageView` (vector drawable) should also change it's color. The problem is, that `EditText` requires two clicks to call the onClick callback. I found a solution by setting its `focusableInTouchMode` attribute to `false`. However, using this solution, the focus get lost.

Maybe I should solve this programmatically by overriding a onFocus callback for the `EditText` and redirect to the onClick Method and also set the focus for the `ImageView` there. But this seems to be bad practice in case of reusability.

So, what´s a good practice for combining the features of these two views?

Answer (score 0):

Set a `View.onClickListener` on the `RelativeLayout`, then `requestFocus()` on your `EditText`.

```
mYourRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mYourEditText.requestFocus();
    }
});
```

Comment: what do you mean? "doesn't remain"? You lose focus on the `EditText` again?

Comment: rocking any fancy `onFocusChangedListeners`?

Comment: Yes, I´m trying this callback at the moment. But it seems that the requestFocus() never works (I have set focusable to true).

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: an `EditText` is always `focusableInTouchMode`. Seems like your problem was setting it to false in the first place. Glad you got it working.

Comment: I´ve replaced the EditText, because only one View can have the focus at one time but I want the RelativeLayout (default on focusableInTouchMode is false) to gain it. But also have the "focus animation" of the EditText, so i "faked" the EditText by a TextView with a divider which get animated programmatically.